# Answers not getting accepted for Android questions

Tags: discussion, support, questions, answers, android

Not sure if anyone else is experiencing this, but I've noticed that the majority of the Android questions that I've answered (with correct answers) are not acknowledged at all - the user who asked the question just leaves it without awarding anyone anything.

I understand that with the boom of Android there are lots of new users just registering to ask questions and don't bother to come back once they get the answer they need.

I just feel like I'm wasting my time even answering their question if I can't get at least a bit of acknowledgment or a thanks.

I thought the whole purpose of this community was to help each other out, but it's apparent that a lot of the new users don't give a rats arse about anyone else, and they just care about getting what they need, then hit the road.

Is there any way I can still get credit for all the answers I've given in relation to Android question, where the user just ditched?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm. This looks unusual, but on the other hand, the vast majority of questions and answers isn't that old yet (a few days at most). I'd tend to say wait some more time, plus if your answers are good, they will gain upvotes along the way.

Comment: Yeah, I'm hoping that in a few more days they'll be recognized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Sir, are correct:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/290/percentage-of-questions-with-accepted-answers-based-on-tags

Of all tags with over 2000 questions, `[android]` is third from last, with only 51% of all questions having an accepted answer.